# Should you add specific garden-fresh herbs to a stew at the beginning or the end?

Tags: soup, herbs

There are several questions about when to add spices and herbs to soup, but this one is more specific. I'm making a stew that is to be thickened with roux. A soupy tomato based soup will be simmered for a few hours, blended, chilled, then added to a roux to thicken.

I have a variety of garden herbs that I'd like to cut and add; specifically some combination of basil, oregano, thyme and summer savory.

Should I add these to the soup as it is simmered, so they will be blended and incorporated? Or should I mince the herbs and stir them into the thickened stew at the end.

Mind you, this isn't a *bouquet garni* situation where you flavor the stock as it simmers, I'm experimenting with incorporate a larger volume of fresh herbs into the meal itself as a principal component; something I picked up from the heavy use of dill and parsley in some spanakopita recipes.  I want the herbs to provide a green bulk to the stew, but I also want the flavors to persist.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the herbs.

Something like thyme or rosemary or oregano can withstand cooking for a long time and should be removed before eating or blending (IMO)

Other herbs like basil will not withstand long cooking time and should be added raw at the end, or at serving time to have their full flavor shine.